# Can some theory of complex differential equations yield similar results?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to find all complex values $c$ such that the complex differential equation

$$y'(z) = \frac{y}{c + z}$$

is satisfied.

Can I assume this complex-valued differential equation is satisfied by some type of comparable integral equation, like

$$y(z) = \exp \left(\int_{z_0}^{z}\frac{dw}{c+w} \right)?$$
How do we sort through this?

Answer (score 0):

At least there's the heuristic symbol-manipulation sequence
$$
{y'\over y} \;=\; {1\over c+z}
$$
from which, integrating, for some constant $C$,
$$
\log y \;=\; \log(c+z)+C 
$$
Yes, with complex numbers, there is inescapable ambiguity of logs by integer multiples of $2\pi i$. But exponentiating eliminates this:
$$
y \;=\; e^C\cdot (c+z)
$$
Your integral expression gives the same thing, ... :)

Comment: Well, in the complex plane, you typically take contour integrals, correct? Is there a way to define the log function as a complex integral solution to the differential equation? I could have sworn there was some famous theorem that you can represent any complex valued function as a contour integral of a singularity.